# Install Joomla on NGINX in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: mysql, nginx, joomla

I'm installing Joomla on NGINX and so far everything is going fine until I get to the page where is checks Pre-Installation parameters. It says

> Database Support : No

[image]

I've already checked MySQL installation and everything is fine. I have made a MySQL database called "joomladb".

Please help!

Comment: Do you grand access to db for joomla user?

Comment: Yes I've granted the access through this command.
`GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON joomla.* TO 'joomla_admin'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'joomla_admin_password';`

Comment: Are the mysql(i) extension modules loaded? Please show us your phpinfo() output related to MySQL.

Comment: phpinfo() doesn't show anything related to MySQL or even SQL.

Comment: Oh you mean 'php5-mysql'? Yes it's installed but still I'm getting this error.

Comment: If phpinfo() doesn't show anything related, and the file `/etc/php5/conf.d/mysql.ini`'s content is `extension=mysql.so`, than you have to check your Apache logs. By the way, have you restarted Apache?

Comment: I'm using NGINX not Apache.

Comment: The nginx error log is available at: `/var/log/nginx/error.log`. Please check it to find exact error.

Answer (score 0):

Since you said you name your database "joomladb", you should use the same name when you grant permission to database user as in

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON joomladb.* TO "joomla_admin"@"localhost" 
IDENTIFIED BY "joomla_admin_password";
```